# Can't see some properties in Excel Interop from F#

Tags: f#, c#-to-f#, f#-3.0

I'm using the `Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel` library (version 14.0) from an F# application and I can't seem to be able to reference some of the properties defined in Interop's interfaces/classes.

For example, if I have a `Worksheet` object I can't do the following:

```
let sht = // Get the Worksheet
sht.PageSetup.CenterHeader <- // Set the header
```

It can't find `CenterHeader` as a property of the `PageSetup` interface, even though it's there if I view the Interop dll in the object browser.

Just for reference, the Interop dll that I'm using is from the VS directory: `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Visual Studio Tools for Office\PIA\Office14\Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.dll`

**Update**:
I actually spoke too soon. Unfortunately the suggested solution with the cast didn't work either. VS thinks it's OK but it fails at runtime with the following error:

`Unable to cast COM object of type 'System.__ComObject' to interface type 'Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.IPageSetup'. This operation failed because the QueryInterface call on the COM component for the interface with IID '{000208B4-0001-0000-C000-000000000046}' failed due to the following error: No such interface supported (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80004002 (E_NOINTERFACE)).`

Comment: I don't know to much about these interop-libs but `CenterHeader` is probably defined in some interface and you have to *cast* `sht.PageSetup` first (like `(sht.PageSetup :> ISomeInterface).CenterHeader <- ...`)

Comment: I think it's here: [`IPageSetup.CenterHeader`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.ipagesetup.centerheader(v=office.11).aspx) - so it's `(sht.PageSetup :> IPageSetup).CenterHeader <- yourString`)

Comment: Thank you sir! That did the trick...but you have to use `:?>` instead of `:>`. If you put it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: sure - sorry about the `:?>` totally missed this

Comment: Weird - `let f (w:Worksheet) = w.PageSetup.CenterHeader` compiles fine for me (albeit with the Office15 version of the interop assembly).

Comment: Just tried it with the Office15 version and had the same problem...I'm not sure what's going on but I suspect that somehow the compiler is getting confused. This is a project within a bigger solution with multiple projects (C# and F#) and some of the other projects use the interop assembly (not all use the same version, either) as well.

Comment: `> let f (w:Worksheet) = w.PageSetup.CenterHeader;;

  let f (w:Worksheet) = w.PageSetup.CenterHeader;;
  ----------------------------------^^^^^^^^^^^^
> 
C:\Users\xxxxx\AppData\Local\Temp\2\stdin(17,35): error FS0039: The field, constructor or member 'CenterHeader' is not defined`

Comment: `let f (w:Worksheet) = (w.PageSetup :?> IPageSetup).CenterHeader;;

val f : w:Worksheet -> string`

Comment: well I'm out here sorry - not gonna mess with COM ;)

Comment: Does any of the other libraries you're referencing also define a `Worksheet` type?

Comment: I created a new project (within the same solution as before) and just referenced the Excel interop from from there. Everything works then. However, when I try to add a reference to another project (in the same solution) that also references the interop assembly (the same version), the compiler cannot find `CenterHeader` again. This "other" project happens to be in C# not in F# but I don't think that would cause a problem. Also, there isn't any other `Worksheet` type in the entire solution.

Comment: @siki - if the C# project uses `Worksheet` and if the project is set to embed interop types, then a copy of `Worksheet` with only a subset of its members will be embedded in the resulting C# output assembly.  If that's what's happening, then you might want to see if setting "Embed Interop Types" to false fixes your problem.

Comment: @kvb - Thanks, I think that's along the right path. Embed Interop Types is currently set to `true` in that other C# project. However, when I try to set it to `false` it just creates a bunch of error in that project, so I don't think I can do that. However, is there a way that I can tell VS not to use the "exported" interop assembly from the C# project in my F# project, but rather use the one that's reference in the F# project itself?

Comment: @siki - I don't think so; as far as I'm aware when NoPIA support was added to the CLR in the .NET 4.0 timeframe no changes were made to the F# compiler to deal with type equivalence (unfortunately), which is probably the root cause of your issue.  What sort of errors do you see when you set Embed Interop Types to false?

Comment: @kvb - I ended up setting `Embed Interop Types` to `false` and fixed the errors it created - basically just had to change a bunch of implicit casts to explicit ones. After this everything works. Thanks a lot and please put this as an answer so that I can accept it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I said in the comments, F# doesn't support [type equivalence for embedded interop types](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd997297(v=vs.110).aspx), so if a C# project has Embed Interop Types enabled then the F# compiler may be unable to determine which version of the interop type to use.  Since the type embedded in the C# output assembly has been stripped down to only the members used, this can make it so that the F# compiler is unable to see members that are present in the version of the type from the primary interop assembly.

The workaround is to turn off Embed Interop Types on the C# project.

Comment: I have turned this off - and it [still doesn't work](https://github.com/dotnet/fsharp/issues/11928).

Answer (score -1):

This works for me:

```
#if INTERACTIVE
#r "office"
#r "Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel"
#endif

open Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel

let setCenterHeader fileName worksheet header =
    let file = System.IO.FileInfo(fileName)
    let excel = ApplicationClass()
    try
        // Make sure to use full path since this will
        // be interpreted as relative to Excel's process,
        // not currently executing one
        let workbook = excel.Workbooks.Open(file.FullName)
        let sheet = workbook.Worksheets.[worksheet] :?> Worksheet

        sheet.PageSetup.CenterHeader <- header

        workbook.Save()
    finally
        excel.Application.Quit()

setCenterHeader "TestWorksheet.xlsx" "Sheet1" "My header 1"
setCenterHeader "TestWorksheet.xlsx" "Sheet2" "My header 2"
setCenterHeader "TestWorksheet.xlsx" "Sheet3" "My header 3"
```

You might want to make sure you have matching versions of PIA and Office installed/used.